# Linux Copy a directory but with a different name?

Tags: linux, bash, copy

I have a directory that I want to copy all of it, but to a directory with a different name.

Example:

```
/Home/user/DirA-Web
```

copy its contents to (but it needs to be created)

```
/Home/user/version1/DirB-Img
/Home/user/version2/DirB-Img
```

I could always copy it and the rename it, I suppose.

Edit: I currently `rsync` the directories to the desired location and them `mv` in a `for` loop to rename them. I am looking for something cleaner.

Comment: do you want to keep initial directory?

Comment: Yes as files get added to it

Comment: why not create a new directory and copy the content to it?

Comment: That is what I am doing essentially. I `rsync` the directories to the new location and then run an `mv` in a `for` loop to rename them. I was looking for a more elegant approach. Something cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

If the directory

```
/Home/user/version1/
```

exists, a simple `cp` will do:

```
cp -r /Home/user/DirA-Web /Home/user/version1/DirB-Img
```

If not, you need to use `mkdir` beforehand, because cp has no option to
create your target directory recursively:

```
mkdir -p /Home/user/version1/DirB-Img && cp -r /Home/user/DirA-Web /Home/user/version1/DirB-Img
```